# Responsive Off Screen Navigation jQuery Plugin Methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to hide the slide navigation menu on demand but I cant figure out how to either call the closeNav method or expose it as a public property. Can someone check out the code and possibly advise I way to do so? Thanks in advance. http://jsfiddle.net/ryanoc/nykxw34a/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.the-nav').cbFlyout();
    // $('.the-nav').closeNav();
});
```

Comment: I guess its hiding right?? Your fiddle looks fine!!

Comment: I want to programmatically close it for possible async calls though. Right now you have to either refresh the page, click the body or click the hamburger icon.